# internetMessageHeaders now available using graph api endpoint for messages in the sent items folder

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Originally posted by @jasonjoh in https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2716

Regarding answer given by https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2716#issuecomment-580751583
*No, internet headers just do not exist on the copy in Sent Items.*

For shared mailbox messages in the sent items folder, we recently noticed using the graph api endpoint "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/sentitems/messages?$select=internetMessageHeaders" we can access the headers. This was not the case earlier, so can we get a confirmation that this new feature can be relied upon.

Comment: Let me test this out and confirm the same in shared mailbox messages, wherein the internetmsgheaders functionality added a while ago.

Comment: yeah, i can confirm it works!!